# I need to remove right border when line breaks

Tags: html, css, web

I have list inline-block with right border after every element.
Problem: I need to remove right border when line breaks, how can I do it? Doesn't depend on the length, just need to remove it before every line break.

```css
ul{
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

li{
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);

}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Any text</li>
  <li>Any text</li>
  <li>Any text different</li>
  <li>Any text</li>
  <li>Any text different</li>
  <li>Any text sas s as s</li>
  
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Problem: I need to remove right border when line breaks, how can I do it?

There is no easy way to do that. CSS has no mechanism to select an element based on where a line breaks, or whether it is the "last" item on a line.

But - you can do it the other way around. Put the border on the left side of the items, move them all to the left by one pixel - and have the UL cut off any overflow.

```css
ul {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -1px;
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Any text</li>
    <li>Any text</li>
    <li>Any text different</li>
    <li>Any text</li>
    <li>Any text different</li>
    <li>Any text sas s as s</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's not right way for me, because I can't just hide it. I need to make the elements centered and everything will be visible

Comment: That absolutely changes the context of your question. There is no similar trick to apply when the items should be centered. You will have to use JavaScript then, to "check" which items are the first/last on a row, and add the border to those dynamically. And it will need some sort of resize observer then, too, if you want it to update when the browser window width changes.

Answer (score 0):

This is hacky so probably just for fun, but if you give each li a before pseudo element with both left and right border of white and position them correctly they will overlay each other.

Then apply mix-blend-mode: difference - two whites make a black so the bar will be seen but if there is only one bar then as it's white it won't be:

```css
ul {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

li::before {
  content: '';
  border-right: 1px white solid;
  border-left: 1px white solid;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 1.5px;
  padding-right: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Any text</li>
  <li>Any text</li>
  <li>Any text different</li>
  <li>Any text</li>
  <li>Any text different</li>
  <li>Any text sas s as s</li>

</ul>
```